# How inspect CSS vendor prefix in browser?

Tags: css, browser, cross-browser

I found a [snippet of SCSS](https://github.com/darlanrod/input-range-scss) that I'm trying to use.

It contains CSS vendor prefixes that I'm unfamiliar with:

- `::-webkit-slider-runnable-track`
- `::-webkit-slider-thumb`
- `::-moz-range-track`
- `::-ms-fill-lower`
- etc

I'd love to use Chrome or some other browser's "developer tools" / Inspect to be able to play around with colors and dimensions, but **I can't find where these particular CSS rules are.**

All I can find is my `input` element: `<input type="range" id="position" name="position" min="0" step=".1" max="70" value="70">`

Currently, I'm editing SCSS in Netbeans, and it compiles to CSS on each save, and then I refresh my browser.

It's time-consuming, and I'd also really like to see where those rules take affect when I highlight an element in the inspector.

I appreciate any suggestions.

P.S. I figured there would be a way to show them, like there is for `active`, `focus`, `hover`, and `visited` rules.

Comment: Have you found a answer to that? If so, It would be very nice if you could share it with us. I have a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71133738

Comment: @guilfer Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 3):

The vendor prefixes are actually considered **pseudo-selectors**, and as such, create their own CSS **selectors**. You won't see them in the CSS states such as `:hover` and `:active`, but rather as independent CSS **rules**:

```
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-thumb
input[type='range']::-moz-range-track
input[type='range']::-ms-fill-lower
```

This is illustrated in the example below, which has different displays on the different browsers:

```css
input[type='range'] {
  width: 210px;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type='range'],
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track,
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 200px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #AAA;
}

input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background: steelblue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="range" id="position" name="position" min="0" step=".1" max="70" value="70">
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I appreciate your answer and gave you a vote, but this is blowing my mind: when I click "Run code snippet" on your answer (in Chrome) and then right-click and "Inspect" on the input range, I immediately see in the "Styles" tab of the developer tools exactly what I was hoping to see. But on my *own* site (i.e. my own similar implementation), when I do the same Inspect, I see none of those pseudo selectors (even though their styles are successfully working). Bizarre.

Comment: Its happening to mee too. Cant view pseudo selectors when I inspect my app, however, I can see this pseudo selector in this answer...

Comment: I think I got his trick! He not only added the pseudo selectors, but also the input[type='range] selector (without pseudo selector) itself for this style rule, and this is visible in the dev tools:

**input[type='range']**, input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track, input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
}

Answer (score 0):

I finally could find an option on Chrome Dev Tools to show the user-agend pseudo-elements.

Basically you have to go to "Preferences" and scroll to the "Elements" section, where there is a option for that.

[Webkit Pseudo Elements Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71133738)